# Centering a Col/Card-panel in materialize

Tags: html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s5 m5 l5">
<div class="card-panel small blue z-depth-3 center-align">
<h1> Hello </h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is center the card panel in the column using Materialize's helper class `center-align` which didn't work, i also tried using that class on the `col s5 m5 l5` element, which also didn't work

can anyone suggest ways to fix this? even if it has to be CSS

**EDIT**: I did try using materialize's offset utility but it just messes up quite alot

Comment: Don't we forget some dashes?

Comment: @AlonEitan It doesn't work with dashes? that's bootstrap

Comment: Oh, sorry about that :)

Comment: @AlonEitan That's fine :-)

Comment: Don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve centering when you push / pull your columns around. You have a total of 12 cols in a row and lets make your column 6 wide instead of 5 for the sake of the example.

```
  <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col s6 offset-s3"><span class="flow-text">Centered</span></div>
  </div>
```

I have divided my row as 3 - 6 - 3 which totals on 12 and the column I want is centered. Check out push / pull examples

Comment: I really cannot use the offset classes to be honest as I've edited quite a number of classes in Materialize's css file which messed it up, but I'll just stick to that and try to fix it. Thanks.